# Rickrolling Anniversary

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

What is the significance of this?

```
638370466620448309680870                || 
638370466620538096803696                ||L
6383704666207860276863026303373780968   ||A
638370466620625309680279                || 
63837046662072904663293                 || 
63837046662083550205430263048780968     ||R
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If

> ```
> 0=SPACE
> 2=abc
> 3=def
> 4=ghi
> 5=jkl
> 6=mno
> 7=pqrs
> 8=tuv
> 9=wxyz
> (based off the letters on a phone number pad)
> ```

Then

> The numbers can be decoded to the lyrics of the chorus of 'Never gonna give you up' by Rick Astley.
>
> ```
> Never gonna give you up
> Never gonna let you down
> Never gonna run around and desert you
> Never gonna make you cry
> Never gonna say goodbye
> Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
> ```

And then

> We apply the reverse operation on the right side, which yields `052007`. Interpret this as "05/2007", or May 2007. This is the month when the original rick-roll on YT was released. [This scholarly article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) agrees.

Comment: So close! rot13(ZQL naq LQZ nera'g gur bayl cbffvoyr qngr sbezngf) :)

Comment: Scholarly article, my foot!

Comment: @Stiv It's the primary source, what more could you ask?

Comment: @Stiv Now, now, you know the rules.  And so do I.

Comment: I fixed your decode key (s is 7 not 8) and added the source.